# How can I batch rename attachments I've exported?

Tags: attachment, data-export

I'm trying to rename exported attachments using the mac instructions here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232859&type=1

But I'm receiving a No such file or directory error and I can't seem to troubleshoot it.

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] to help the community help you.  You're going to need to use [edit] to add more details

Comment: You are very likely running the script in the wrong directory. It needs to be in the same directory as the attachment files.

Answer (score 3):

Hoping this helps as I just had this same issue. One of my problems was that there are multiple Attachment folders in the export you get from Salesforce, but they're all listed in the CSV, so when you follow those instructions and then try to run that rename.sh file in one directory, it's looking for files in the other directory too. So I did it twice, one in each directory, and it just gave me the "no such file or directory" error for the ones that were in the other folder only.

That being said, I had to modify the directions a bit to get it work, as well as the terminal command lines. Also, I downloaded SublimeText to use instead of TextEdit on Mac, as you need the file to save in a way that it won't see the line returns as characters (the first time I did this using the file I created in TextEdit, it worked but added "?" to the end of every filename. Not helpful. The internet told me it has to do with the way applications encode the text files, so to be safe I tried SublimeText instead and it worked). So, here are my amended instructions:

1. Open the file "Attachment.csv" in Excel
2. Delete all columns but "ID" and "Name". Once all the other columns are deleted, "ID" should be in column A and "Name" should be in column B.
3. Copy the formula on the following line and paste it into cell C2.

   ```
   ="mv "&A2&" """&B2&""""
   ```
4. The resulting cell should look like this:

   ```
   mv 00P300000046RlaEAE "Technical Specifications V1_2.docx"
   ```
5. Double-click the lower right corner of cell C2 to copy all the way down to column C.
6. Select column C and copy it.
7. Open SublimeText (not TextEdit on Mac).
8. Paste the copied cells into SublimeText.
9. Save as in SublimeText, and save the file in your exported Attachments Folder as "Rename.sh" (without the quotation marks).  This is where the records to be renamed are located -- *(Either move all your attachments into this folder first after you hunt through all the unzipped folders to ensure you find them all, or repeat this process in each folder)*.
10. Open terminal
11. Type "cd" (without the quotes) and then drag the folder containing the attachments and the rename.sh file into terminal so it copies the directory exactly and press enter. That moves you into the right directory. You can type "pwd" without quotes and enter to have it confirm which director you are in.
12. Type sudo chmod 777 "Rename.sh" -- no quotes, insert your filename there (case sensitive I think). It should prompt you for your password - this gives the system permission to run the file.
13. Type sudo ./"Rename.sh " -- again no quotes, just your filename.
14. You should see it run and then you should see all the names update in the folder.
15. Close "Attachment.csv" in Excel without saving any changes.

ALSO NOTE: If you have attachments that are individual unqiue attachment Ids but have the same name (meaning the file was likely attached more than once, or could have been attached to different records with the same file name), it appears it merges them all into one file with that filename. I couldn't figure out why my file count in the finder folders was lower than the number of rows in the Attachments csv and after some sleuthing I realized there were rows that ended up as one file. If you want these to stay as separate, I'd suggest looking for duplicates in the Excel file in the name column and modifying the names so you end up with a 1:1 relationship between rows in Attachments.csv and files in the folder.

Comment: This is very helpful - I hadn't realized it would merge all the files with the same name. We have many duplicates so I'll have to tackle those before I can try your modified directions. I do have 75 folders worth of attachments as well, which complicates this.

Comment: 75 folders! Wow. I thought it was annoying with just 2. There may be a way with mv to keep the dupe merging from happening but I'm not familiar enough with terminal to go hunting that down. Good luck! I actually work at Salesforce so I reached out asking for someone to update that knowledge article with more updated info.